# Switch DNX Version in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I started a new web project using dnu and dnx.  I was able to open it in Visual Studio and all was working great.  Now I installed the Facebook SDK nuget package, but it isn't compatible with DNX Core 5.0.  I have two sets of references, one for `DNX Core 5.0` and one for `DNX 4.5.1`.  When I compile I get errors because the types can't be found, although I can enter them fine in code and intellisense works.

I can't find anywhere where the version is set.  In `global.json` it says my version is '1.0.0-rc1-final' which looks like 'clr' runtime, not 'coreclr'.  Does that mean it's 4.5.1?  It seems to have no relation to those versions.

[image: dnvm versions]

Looking in project.json I see facebook is there only for framework 'dnx451', if I add it to 'dnxcore50' then I get an error that Facebook 7.0.6 does not support DNXCore, Version=v5.0.

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Facebook": "7.0.6"
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Facebook": "7.0.6"
    }
  }
},
```

A search of the entire project finds that this is the only place those strings exist.  Doing a recursive grep from the command line shows there are many lines with those strings in the paths (i.e. `lib/dnxcore50/`).  The parent seems to be `DNXCore,Version=v5.0`.

Doing a full search for DNX I find web config has an httpPlatform entry:

```
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%"
         arguments="%DNX_ARGS%"
         stdoutLogEnabled="false"
         forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"
         startupTimeLimit="3600" />
```

How do I tell my project to use framework `dnx451`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep referencing dnxcore50 as a possible target framework Visual Studio will prevent you from building unless all the referenced packages are compatible with it. It tries to ensure that you can run the application on both of the frameworks.

You can simply remove the dnxcore50 from the frameworks to remove the dependencies and make sure you're always building for dnx451.

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Facebook": "7.0.6"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: OMFG, so simple...  I thought that section was just for framework-dependent dependencies...

Comment: It is super simple indeed. It combines both the dependencies per framework and the frameworks you target (you can have certain dependencies that are only needed for one framework). Glad to help you out.

Comment: Worth noting that the *dnxcore50* target is the super slick new self-contained, ultra portable and supercool future awesome feature, but for now it's usually not worth supporting it in your applications.